# Webcam not opening in google chrome over mobile

Tags: javascript

```
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function(stream) {
        alert("here")
        stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
            pc.addTrack(track, stream);
        });
        return negotiate();
    }, function(err) {
        alert('Could not acquire media: ' + err);
    });
```

Here i am using this code to open webcam .
This code works fine in web browser.

But, this code does not work for chrome browser in mobile.

I cheked by adding alert. This alert is coming only on web but, not coming in mobile.

Please take a look what will be issue

Comment: Be sure to use https or localhost, otherwise it won't work

Comment: https://betadatascience.smartshop.social/

I use https

Comment: You can test in mobile chrome browser

Comment: Check your mobile console for errors, guide on google how to get them

Comment: how can i see mobile console ?